# How to go about creating embeddings (especially, token to Id mapping) for categorical columns in tensorflow 2.0+?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-datasets, word-embedding

I have a csv with both categorical and float dtypes. I want to do the following:

1. For each categorical column i will use pandas to compute the unique values (`pd.unique()`) that are present in the column. say `u_l` for a column
2. I will use the `len(u_l)` to decide upon the dimension of embeddings that i use for a particular categorical column that i want i embed (this step is the reason i cannot use tensorflow_transform)
3. I want to create some stateful node that can map `category (token)` value to embeddings index thus subsequently i can lookup the embedding from embeddings matrix that i created in step 2

I dont know how to go about doing it currently. A very inelegant solution i can see is using tensorflow_datasets:

1. `encoder = tfds.features.text.TokenTextEncoder(u_l,decode_token_separator=' ')`
2. concatenate the entire column using space delimiter (`c_l`) (`c_l` is one string now) and then using `encoder.encode(c_l)`

This is a very basic thing that i think tensorflow would be able to do relatively easily. Please guide me to the right solution

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use your word corpus as embedding like if you have corpus as this :

corpus :

1. "This pasta is good"
2. "This pasta is very good"

and you want to use embedding you can use `Tokenizer` of TF see [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/text/Tokenizer). It will create a `dict` containing words as keys and index as value like in above corpus dict looks like :

word_index = {"this" : 1, "pasta" : 2, "good" : 3, "very" : 4}
you can avoid stopwords.

Now you can make word embedding vector using these word_index dict so that it looks like

1. For corpus 1 : [1, 2, 3]
2. For corpus 2 : [1, 2, 4, 3]

Enough talk let see some code :  Also define `oov_token` for out of vocabulary words.

You can do like this :

```py
vocab_size = 10000
embedding_dim = 16
max_length = 120
trunc_type='post'
oov_tok = "<OOV>"

from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer


tokenizer = Tokenizer(num_words = vocab_size, oov_token=oov_tok)
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(training_sentences)
word_index = tokenizer.word_index 
sequences = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(training_sentences) # This will create word embedding vector
padded = pad_sequences(sequences,maxlen=max_length, truncating=trunc_type) # This will padd zeros according to `trunc_type`, here add zeros in last

testing_sequences = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(testing_sentences)
testing_padded = pad_sequences(testing_sequences,maxlen=max_length)
```

Also see this GitHub [code](https://github.com/Eshan-Agarwal/TensorFlow-in-Practice-Assignments/blob/master/Natural%20Language%20Processing%20in%20TensorFlow/Course_3_Week_2_Exercise_Question.ipynb) of me hope it will help